# How to disable an EditorFor with JavaScript in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to disable any editorfor with javascript, I try this but it's not worked :

```
<body onload="charge()">
    <div class="editor-field">
       <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Num_Serie, new { @id = "nn" })%>        
    </div>
</body>
```

and the javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function charge() {

            var nn = document.getElementById('nn');

            nn.disabled = 'disabled';

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: using Jquery $("#nn").prop('disabled', true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EditorFor` is not rendered into one HTML element, rather it is a collection of inputs. Therefore you should disable all of them:

```
function charge() {
    var inputs = $('div.editor-field :input');
    inputs.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Comment: Precisely what I came here to say - there seems to be a common confusion that a HtmlHelper necessarily equates to a single HTML element, which is not true. Particularly, in fact, with `EditorFor`, where it is impossible to know what will be rendered without seeing both the model and the project's template structure.

Comment: @RabNawaz, true enough. However I assume jquery is there - this is an ASP.NET MVC project, jQuery is included there by default. It is not a problem to rewrite the same without jquery though, but it will require either more details from the OP, or way more javascript code - both will distract from main point.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("nn").disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

for this particular case, this jQuery code will work.
    `$('#nn').attr('disabled','disabled');`